# XSLT: Placing image returning from URL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Gretings,

I'm writing an xslt in which i want to put an image created remotely.

I parse a parameter which I send to a URL, which returns an image if i use it in a browser.

If I use :

```
<img src="http://URL.ashx?paramater=something" height="75" />
```

or

```
<img>
<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="http://URL.ashx?paramater=something"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

they don't work(the whole src works if put in a browser).

Perhaps you can help me. Many thanks in advance.

RS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im gonna answer my own question:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<img src = "1rst-half-URL]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="thumbnail"/> <xsl:value-of select="concat($variable  , '&#38;parameter' )"/> 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[restURL" />]]></xsl:text>
```